# Recursive Fibonacci .. no idea what is going on

Tags: c++, recursion, fibonacci

I recently made a code for a procedural function in c++ application for calculating F(n) in Fibonacci sequence.

Anyway, I can not get it to produce the correct result using recursion. For example whenever I enter the value 5, it returns 8, were my other procedural code returns the correct vale of 5.

This is the function I am using... and the code I got from the net. The problem I have is the code from the net and my code are exactly the same (nearly) but BOTH give the wrong value...

http://codepad.org/pMKs4kvb

What is going on?

Answer (score 3):

Well, simply put, your function is printing out the following series:

```
1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 ...
```

And hence, `F(5) = 8` (if we're talking zero indexed here). If you want the following to be printed:

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 ...
```

Which is the sequence as recognized by OEIS, then all you need to do is make sure you define `F(0) = 0`. To that extent, your function should simply be:

```
int FibiRec(int n) {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
        return n; // IMPORTANT
    } else {
        return FibiRec(n-1) + FibiRec(n-2);
    }
}
```

At the same time I would like to add: Your function has a horrible time complexity of `O(2^n)`. With your function, try generating the 40th or 100th fibonacci number and you'll realize what I'm talking about.

Comment: or you can just simply revise your condition statement to: if (n == 1 || n == 2) {return 1;} else {return FibiRec(n-1) + FibiRec(n-2);}

Comment: @Ikahtz: Which would run till a stack overflow if I am to ever query FibRec(0).

Answer (score 0):

your numbering starts from 0...while the procedural numbering starts from 1

n :    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

F(n) : 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8

Answer (score -1):

I guess you need to add another condition  `n==2` to your if loop...your program should be...

```
int FibiRec(int n){
        int result = 0;
        if (n == 0 || n == 1 || n==2){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return FibiRec(n-1) + FibiRec(n-2);
        }
    }
```

This is because, for n=2, FibiRec(1) and FibiRec(0) will be called , which are your stop conditions....

Comment: Well, according to your function, F(0) = F(1) = F(2) = 1. Other than that, since we know that F(n) is defined in terms of F(n-1) and F(n-2), then why would we ever need 3 explicit definitions as the 3rd, by definition is defined in terms of the first 2?

Comment: I assumed that, he is asking the user for a position(n) in the series....by which the 2nd position will hold the value "1"....